# Linq update with join

Tags: c#, linq

I have this two collections

```
var materials = new List<Models.Material>();
materials.Add(new Models.Material { Number = 111, Value = null });
materials.Add(new Models.Material { Number = 222, Value = null });

var db_materials = new List<Models.DB_Material>();
db_materials.Add(new Models.DB_Material { Number = 111, ValueColumn = 10});
db_materials.Add(new Models.DB_Material { Number = 222, ValueColumn = 20 });
db_materials.Add(new Models.DB_Material { Number = 333, ValueColumn = 30 });
db_materials.Add(new Models.DB_Material { Number = 444, ValueColumn = 40 });
```

and i need to update all **Value** properties in **materials** collection with **ValueColumn** in **db_materials** collection.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested following code and it works

```
            var joins = from material in materials
                        join db_material in db_materials on material.Number equals db_material.Number
                        select new { material = material, db = db_material};

            foreach (var join in joins)
            {
                join.material.Value  = join.db.ValueColumn;
            }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I think that joins collection contains references to original two collections. Foreach then updates the specific value. The problem i realized is that when one collection is `IList<Material>` and other is `DbSet<Material>` the join throws error that `The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'` I dont know how to solve this, but maybe it is specific for another SO question.

Comment: I tried to explain it more specific in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086962/update-collection-from-dbset-object-via-linq?noredirect=1#comment89162858_51086962

Comment: Is number a string or an integer?  The Material Class shows it as a string but I can't tell the db if it is also a string.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it without joins.
Try below snippet:

```
materials.ForEach(x => x.Value = db_materials.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Number == x.Number).ValueColumn);
```

**ForEach()** will update values in original instance itself. No need to use loop or joins.

Comment: This is very elegant, thank you :) It updates Number property instead of Value property. `materials.ForEach(x => x.Value = db_materials.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Number == x.Number).ValueColumn);` is working for me.

Comment: Yeah it was typo, updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Update main collection using AND query as well, for which you need to join with first column and then where clause with second column to update. You can check example here, 
https://codeshowtime.blogspot.com/2020/01/linq-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

Here it is without join:

```
  materials =  materials.Select(c => { c.Value = db_materials.Where(dbm => dbm.Number == c.Number).ToList().FirstOrDefault().Value; return c; }).ToList();
```

Comment: This violates the functional character of LINQ. LINQ methods aren't supposed to modify objects flowing through there pipeline.