# Update collection from DbSet object via Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i know it is not complicated but i struggle with it.

I have `IList<Material>` collection

```
public class Material
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}

materials = new List<Material>();

materials.Add(new Material { Number = 111 });
materials.Add(new Material { Number = 222 });
```

And i have `DbSet<Material>` collection
 with columns *Number* and *ValueColumn*

I need to update `IList<Material>` Value property based on `DbSet<Material>` collection but with following conditions

- Only one query request into database
- The returned data from database has to be limited by Number identifier (do not load whole database table into memory)

I tried following (based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083934/linq-update-with-join))

**Working solution 1**, but download whole table into memory (monitored in sql server profiler).

```
var result = (

       from db_m in db.Material
       join m in model.Materials
       on db_m.Number.ToString() equals m.Number

       select new
       {
           db_m.Number,
           db_m.Value
       }

).ToList();

model.Materials.ToList().ForEach(m => m.Value= result.SingleOrDefault(db_m => db_m.Number.ToString() == m.Number).Value);
```

**Working solution 2**, but it execute query for each item in the collection.

```
model.Materials.ToList().ForEach(m => m.Value= db.Material.FirstOrDefault(db_m => db_m.Number.ToString() == m.Number).Value);
```

**Incompletely solution**, where i tried to use contains method

```
// I am trying to get new filtered collection from database, which i will iterate after.
                var result = db.Material
                    .Where(x=> 
                        // here is the reasonable error: cannot convert int into Material class, but i do not know how to solve this.
                        model.Materials.Contains(x.Number)
                    )
                    .Select(material => new Material { Number = material.Number.ToString(), Value = material.Value});
```

Any idea ? For me it is much easier to execute stored procedure with comma separated id values as a parameter and get the data directly, but i want to master linq too.

Comment: Working solution 1 -- there's no `where` clause on your query. Take off the `.ToList()` in the `result` and it will be lazy loaded.

Comment: `The returned data from database has to be limited by Number identifier (do not load whole database table into memory)` -- what's the cut-off / threshold?

Comment: @MarkC. I tried to ommit .ToList() and now it execute query for each item instead of whole table. It is not real performance issue, but i want to learn it right for more complicated requests and also table can grow.

Comment: That's correct, but what is the threshold? You don't want to bring back the entire table - understandable, but what's the criteria? Add that to your `where` clause in "solution 1" and there's nothing else to do

Comment: I want filter the database table to rows which contains values of Number property in IList<Material> collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this without trying to get too cute :

```
var numbersToFilterby = model.Materials.Select(m => m.Number).ToArray();
...
var result = from db_m in db.Material where numbersToFilterBy.Contains(db_m.Number) select new { ... }
```

Comment: oh my, why i did not think about it myself ! Thank you, I'm leaving computer for a while and come together !

Comment: I think you had the right idea (not wanting to pull back entire data set), but were just looking at too many different solutions. You would have gotten this on your own without a doubt, maybe just right after you stepped out for lunch ;)